# htaccess for 2 different type of url for my website

Tags: php, .htaccess

My site is irasol.com. This site has two different type of url that need to RewriteRule in .htaccess.

http://irasol.com/index.php?id=Job-Board&jobid=Technical-UK

Kindly help me rewrite as below.

http://irasol.com/Job-Board/Technical-UK

Thanks for help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?id=$1&jobid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: THanks aleksandar for quicker reply. i had one more url that has to be Rewrite. i am unable to post it due to reputation error. http://irasol.com/index.php?id=About-Us

Comment: The OP wants the url not to be with `.html` at the end.

Comment: I had tried with above rewriterule it is not working.

Comment: I edited the rule so it gives the result you want. Check if mod rewriting is enabled in your apache configuration

Comment: Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?id=$1&jobid=$2 [L] i tried but seems same result in url. kindly check the below link http://irasol.com/index.php?id=Job-Board&jobid=Technical-UK

Comment: that doesnt work that way, try to open this url and see it works:
http://irasol.com/Job-Board/Technical-UK/
but you need to edit your css to work with rewrited url

Comment: i am newbie. Can u please show me how to edit in css. Click on any time it show that id=job-board&jobid=Technical-UK in URL. how to resloved it. THanks for your quicker help.

Comment: Any one please help me to resolve this issue in css. i am newbie. Please help me.